# How do I install ruby-debug-base19x on Mountain Lion for IntelliJ?

Tags: ruby, intellij-idea, rubymine, ruby-debug

I just upgraded to Mountain Lion and it appears that the IntelliJ 10 ruby-debugger no longer works.  I am getting the error below, but can't really interpret how to fix this, any idea?

```
/Users/kamilski81/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p194/bin/ruby extconf.rb
checking for rb_method_entry_t.body in method.h... no
checking for vm_core.h... no
/Users/kamilski81/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194@sc/gems/ruby_core_source-0.1.5/lib/ruby_core_source.rb:39: Use RbConfig instead of obsolete and deprecated Config.
checking for rb_method_entry_t.body in method.h... no
checking for vm_core.h... yes
checking for iseq.h... yes
checking for insns.inc... yes
checking for insns_info.inc... yes
checking for eval_intern.h... yes
creating Makefile

make
compiling breakpoint.c
compiling ruby_debug.c
ruby_debug.c:24:19: error: conflicting types for 'rb_iseq_compile_with_option'
RUBY_EXTERN VALUE rb_iseq_compile_with_option(VALUE src, VALUE file, VALUE line, VALUE opt); /* from iseq.c */
                  ^
/Users/kamilski81/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p194/include/ruby-1.9.1/ruby-1.9.3-p194/vm_core.h:505:7: note: previous declaration is here
VALUE rb_iseq_compile_with_option(VALUE src, VALUE file, VALUE filepath, VALUE line, VALUE opt);
      ^
ruby_debug.c:474:60: warning: implicit conversion loses integer precision: 'long' to 'int' [-Wshorten-64-to-32]
    return rb_funcall2(context, idAtLine, RARRAY_LEN(args) - 1, RARRAY_PTR(args) + 1);
           ~~~~~~~~~~~                    ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~^~~
ruby_debug.c:538:13: warning: implicit conversion loses integer precision: 'long' to 'int' [-Wshorten-64-to-32]
    s_len = RSTRING_LEN(source);
            ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
/Users/kamilski81/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p194/include/ruby-1.9.1/ruby/ruby.h:674:6: note: expanded from macro 'RSTRING_LEN'
     RSTRING_EMBED_LEN(str) : \
     ^
/Users/kamilski81/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p194/include/ruby-1.9.1/ruby/ruby.h:670:6: note: expanded from macro 'RSTRING_EMBED_LEN'
     (long)((RBASIC(str)->flags >> RSTRING_EMBED_LEN_SHIFT) & \
     ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
ruby_debug.c:538:13: warning: implicit conversion loses integer precision: 'long' to 'int' [-Wshorten-64-to-32]
    s_len = RSTRING_LEN(source);
            ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
/Users/kamilski81/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p194/include/ruby-1.9.1/ruby/ruby.h:675:28: note: expanded from macro 'RSTRING_LEN'
     RSTRING(str)->as.heap.len)
                           ^
ruby_debug.c:539:13: warning: implicit conversion loses integer precision: 'size_t' (aka 'unsigned long') to 'int' [-Wshorten-64-to-32]
    f_len = strlen(file);
          ~ ^~~~~~~~~~~~
ruby_debug.c:684:98: error: too few arguments to function call, expected 5, have 4
        rb_str_new_cstr("begin\nend"), rb_str_new_cstr("(exception catcher)"), INT2FIX(1), Qfalse);
                                                                                                 ^
/Users/kamilski81/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p194/include/ruby-1.9.1/ruby-1.9.3-p194/vm_core.h:505:1: note: 'rb_iseq_compile_with_option' declared here
VALUE rb_iseq_compile_with_option(VALUE src, VALUE file, VALUE filepath, VALUE line, VALUE opt);
^
ruby_debug.c:1695:10: warning: implicit conversion loses integer precision: 'VALUE' (aka 'unsigned long') to 'int' [-Wshorten-64-to-32]
  return level;
  ~~~~~~ ^~~~~
ruby_debug.c:2310:37: warning: implicit conversion loses integer precision: 'long' to 'int' [-Wshorten-64-to-32]
        int frames = jump_cfp - cfp + 2;
            ~~~~~~   ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~^~~
ruby_debug.c:2378:53: warning: comparison of integers of different signs: 'long' and 'unsigned long' [-Wsign-compare]
            if ((cfp->pc - cfp->iseq->iseq_encoded) >= (cfp->iseq->iseq_size - 1))
                 ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~  ^   ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
ruby_debug.c:2392:27: warning: comparison of integers of different signs: 'int' and 'size_t' (aka 'unsigned long') [-Wsign-compare]
            for (i = 0; i < cfp->iseq->insn_info_size; i++)
                        ~ ^ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
8 warnings and 2 errors generated.
make: *** [ruby_debug.o] Error 1
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

So, I found out that the source of the problem was linecache19, YOU NEED -v 0.5.13 for it to work.

```
gem install ruby-debug-base19x -v 0.11.30.pre10
gem install ruby-debug-ide -v 0.4.17.beta14
curl -L "http://rubyforge.org/frs/download.php/75414/linecache19-0.5.13.gem" -o /tmp/linecache19-0.5.13.gem
gem install /tmp/linecache19-0.5.13.gem
```

However, my guess is that linecache19 -v 0.5.13 will need to be downloaded from http://rubyforge.org/frs/?group_id=8883&release_id=46302

Good luck.

Comment: Works perfectly!!  I have no idea how the @#$% you figured out that exact combination of versions, but you saved me so much time and headache.  Thanks again.

Comment: Thanks dude, you rock.  I've posted an answer that replaces your last command.

Comment: are you kidding me ????? I spent 2 hours on this, and you come up with that magic combinations ?

Comment: $ curl -L "http://rubyforge.org/frs/?group_id=8883&release_id=46302" -o /tmp/linecache19-0.5.13.gem
curl: (7) Failed connect to rubyforge.org:80; Connection refused

$ curl -L "http://rubyforge.org/frs/download.php/75414/linecache19-0.5.13.gem" -o /tmp/linecache19-0.5.13.gem
curl: (7) Failed connect to rubyforge.org:80; Connection refused

Answer (score 2):

I'm using RubyMine, so situation might be little different, but should be same..

You need to install two gems by `gem install`:

```
archive-tar-minitar
ruby_core_source
```

Then, in the IDE, run the debugger. It should build necessary gems by itself. If you encounter some error, then, some gems might be missing, so read the error carefully and install them by gem install.

I tried with freshly installed Mountain Lion with RubyMine 4.5 and my application, it works without problem. (I'm using Xcode 4.4)

Comment: I ran this inside RubyMine and it worked, then tried it inside IntelliJ 10.4 and it started working again.  I think RubyMine may have made a few patches as well...

Answer (score 2):

I used the commands from @Kamilski81's answer but the last one didn't work.  Here are his commands with the last one replaced by commands to download and install:

```
gem install ruby-debug-base19x -v 0.11.30.pre10
gem install ruby-debug-ide -v 0.4.17.beta14
curl -L "http://rubyforge.org/frs/download.php/75414/linecache19-0.5.13.gem" -o /tmp/linecache19-0.5.13.gem
gem install /tmp/linecache19-0.5.13.gem
```

Comment: That curl fails "connection refused" for me

Answer (score 1):

Re: linecache19 - I filed https://github.com/robmathews/linecache19-0.5.13/issues/1 - so you can now get it:

`$ gem install linecache19-patched
Fetching: linecache19-patched-0.5.13.gem (100%)
Successfully installed linecache19-patched-0.5.13
Couldn't find file to include 'VERSION' from lib/linecache19.rb
Installing ri documentation for linecache19-patched-0.5.13
1 gem installed
$`

Answer (score -2):

Use the [debugger](https://rubygems.org/gems/debugger) gem.

Reasons for fork, to quote the [debugger readme](https://github.com/cldwalker/debugger#reason-for-fork):

> - ruby-debug19 maintainer isn't maintaining:
>
>   - Despite patches from ruby core, no gem release in 2+ years! - 9/1/09.
>   - Requests to release a known working 1.9.3 version have been ignored.
>   - Doesn't respond to rubyforge issues and doesn't have github issues open.
> - Current install is painful. Requires either [manually downloading gems from rubyforge](http://blog.wyeworks.com/2011/11/1/ruby-1-9-3-and-ruby-debug) and installing with compiler flags or [recompiling ruby](http://blog.sj26.com/post/12146951658/updated-using-ruby-debug-on-ruby-1-9-3-p0).
> - We need a decent ruby debugger for future rubies!

I have used the new debugger gem with very few problems.